# Mid to late 1990s point-and-click adventure game, protagonist is transformed into a frog/toad

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I'm trying to find a 3d computer game in 3rd person view that I played as a kid on someone's computer a long time ago. I think it was on Windows 95 (could be older). I probably played it around 1999.

It was a point and click adventure where, at one point, the human protagonist is transformed into a frog/toad by a witch near a fountain/well. (This would end the game, as in perhaps you did the sequence of events in the wrong order or you were missing an item/quest and would need to reload.) I also think I remember there being a magnifying glass as one of the toolkit options.

Comment: Take a look at these ones also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227667/90s-or-earlier-computer-game-where-a-troll-turns-you-into-a-frog

Comment: Was it 3d-like or flat?

Comment: it looked similar to The Legend of Kyrandia but the toolkit at the bottom was entirely different

Answer (score 18):

Could it possibly be [Kings Quest V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Quest_V) that you remember? It was published in 1990 and released again with a CD-ROM version in 1992, so it might be a bit early.

A minor antagonist of the game is the [Witch of the Dark Forest](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/The_Witch_(King%27s_Quest_V)), who likes to turn people into toads and other things.

[image: The witch of the Dark Forest from King's Quest V]

She will do it to the hero too if he is not protected by an amulet.

[image: The witch of the Dark Forest casting a spell from King's Quest V]

The Witch does not appear by a fountain though, but there is a pond nearby where one of her victims is trapped as a tree.

[image: The pond with a tree from King's Quest V]

Comment: thanks for looking. unfortunately, i think the title is a bit more esoteric. the witch and protagonist were definitely next to a fountain in some courtyard and there was a toolkit at the bottom of the screen, 90% sure one of the options had a magnifying glass.

Answer (score 10):

It's a bit of a long shot, but your *description* reminded me of [Simon the Sorcerer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_the_Sorcerer) from 1993, where you don't turn into a frog but you shrink and have to interact with a frog that's featured prominently in one scene:
[image: Simon encounters a frog]

Another scene in the game features a witch, but I don't think there's a looking glass.

The artwork is also very similar to Legend of Kyrandia mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 9):

As per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/227956/23243, might it be The 4th Dimension's *[Demon's Lair](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/18306/Demon%27s%20Lair/)* (1993), as per [this review](https://armclub.org.uk/eureka/eureka10.pdf)?

[image: Front cover of Demon's Lair]

> Apparently your village used to be protected by a kind dragon who has been captured and imprisoned in chains (must be pretty strong chains then!). The villages greatest warrior has been sent to release the dragon and stop the terror plaguing the village folk. You are not this warrior though (and you though you stood a fighting chance, huh!) because he has already fallen foul of the enemies that he has dared to face. You are just another member of the village community and have, unfortunately for you, drawn the short straw to go and free the dragon.

....

> Another of the points that I really enjoyed (call me a masochist if you like) was the point at which I mistakenly stayed too close to the witch for too long. Well, the character (whose name, incidentally, is Bob) is turned into a frog. Painful, you might say, but believe me it is useful in certain situations

### Gameplay

Around the 2:00 mark, you see Bob enter into a small door that he could not fit in before, transformed by a green-skinned witch.

Comment: There is also another thing that you might add. In order to end the Frog spell you have to find and bath in a pool that is full of small fountains. The witch is not in that room though.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you can update info like: 1st or 3rd person point of view, 2D o 3D...

Antway quest for glory 1 is very similar to what you describe. The video in minute 12:55 shows hero turned into a frog. [image]

I also remember one part in ECSTATICA where a wizard turns you into a frog, but ECSTATICA is not point and click.

Answer (score -1):

Kingdom o'magic has a magnifying glass in the toolkit options, it is a point and click of late 90s and the main character is green, like an aligator.

Comment: Fixing the grammatical errors would help clarify your answer; there is a kernel of good answer here with some basis for being a legitimate possibility.

Answer (score -2):

In [The Adventures of Willy Beamish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Willy_Beamish) (first released 1991) the main character, Willy, has a pet frog.

https://playclassic.games/games/point-n-click-adventure-dos-games-online/play-the-adventures-of-willy-beamish-online/

[image: title screen showing Willy and his frog]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It would be good though if you could [edit] this answer to copy and paste any relevant text from the pages you've linked to into your answer, so that all the relevant info can be found within the answer itself.

Comment: I don't see how this is a match, since he's a regular boy who only has a pet frog (edit again if I'm wrong).

Comment: as i remember theres a part where a witch transform Willy into frog, but it was only an abstract idea, HQ KQ more relevant

Answer (score -3):

Could it be "Scooter's Magic Castle"?[image: Castle Map]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by explaining why you think it might be the correct answer, i.e. the specific ways in which it matches the game described in the question.